# Cannot pass shell output to IRB

Tags: ruby, macos, shell, irb

I need to pass output from my shell to IRB console and wait for input. But IRB returns nil instead of waiting.

```
> echo "gets" | irb

WARNING: This version of ruby is included in macOS for compatibility with legacy software.
In future versions of macOS the ruby runtime will not be available by
default, and may require you to install an additional package.

Switch to inspect mode.
gets
nil
```

How can I pass a command from outside IRB so that it waits for input?

Comment: How about `ruby -e "gets"` and then you can launch `irb`

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?